# Ошибка в tinyxml при отладке

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

Здравствуйте! Хочу отрисовать карту созданную в Tiled.
На просторах интернета нашел одну интересную фичу (level.h и level.cpp), которая обрабатывает созданный в Tiled .tmx файл (этакий парсер?)

Добавил в проект все файлы tinyxml, level (именно h и cpp).
Компиляция проходит успешно, но вот приложение при запуске крашится.
Как запустить приложение?
[image: Скриншот отладки]

--- main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "Level.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "App");
    Level AppLevel;
    AppLevel.LoadFromFile("Resources/map.tmx");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        AppLevel.Draw(window);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

--- level.h

```
#ifndef LEVEL_H
#define LEVEL_H

#pragma comment(lib,"sfml-graphics.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"sfml-window.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"sfml-system.lib")

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

struct Object
{
    int GetPropertyInt(string name);
    float GetPropertyFloat(string name);
    string GetPropertyString(string name);
    string name;
    string type;
    Rect<int> rect;
    map<string, string> properties;
    Sprite sprite;
};

struct Layer
{
    int opacity;
    vector<Sprite> tiles;
};

class Level
{
public:
    bool LoadFromFile(string filename);
    Object GetObject(string name);
    vector<Object> GetObjects(string name);
    void Draw(RenderWindow &window);
    Vector2i GetTileSize();

private:
    int width, height, tileWidth, tileHeight;
    int firstTileID;
    Rect<float> drawingBounds;
    Texture tilesetImage;
    vector<Object> objects;
    vector<Layer> layers;
};
#endif
```

--- level.cpp

```
#include "level.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "tinyxml.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int Object::GetPropertyInt(string name)
{
    return atoi(properties[name].c_str());
}

float Object::GetPropertyFloat(string name)
{
    return (float)strtod(properties[name].c_str(), NULL);
}

string Object::GetPropertyString(string name)
{
    return properties[name];
}

bool Level::LoadFromFile(string filename)
{
    TiXmlDocument levelFile(filename.c_str());

    if (!levelFile.LoadFile())
    {
        cout << "Loading level \"" << filename << "\" failed." << endl;
        return false;
    }

    TiXmlElement *map;
    map = levelFile.FirstChildElement("map");

    width = atoi(map->Attribute("width"));
    height = atoi(map->Attribute("height"));
    tileWidth = atoi(map->Attribute("tilewidth"));
    tileHeight = atoi(map->Attribute("tileheight"));

    TiXmlElement *tilesetElement;
    tilesetElement = map->FirstChildElement("tileset");
    firstTileID = atoi(tilesetElement->Attribute("firstgid"));

    TiXmlElement *image;
    image = tilesetElement->FirstChildElement("image");
    string imagepath = image->Attribute("source");

    Image img;

    if (!img.loadFromFile(imagepath))
    {
        cout << "Failed to load tile sheet." << endl;
        return false;
    }

    img.createMaskFromColor(Color(109, 159, 185));
    tilesetImage.loadFromImage(img);
    tilesetImage.setSmooth(false);

    int columns = tilesetImage.getSize().x / tileWidth;
    int rows = tilesetImage.getSize().y / tileHeight;

    vector<Rect<int>> subRects;

    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            Rect<int> rect;

            rect.top = y * tileHeight;
            rect.height = tileHeight;
            rect.left = x * tileWidth;
            rect.width = tileWidth;

            subRects.push_back(rect);
        }

    TiXmlElement *layerElement;
    layerElement = map->FirstChildElement("layer");
    while (layerElement)
    {
        Layer layer;

        if (layerElement->Attribute("opacity") != NULL)
        {
            float opacity = (float)strtod(layerElement->Attribute("opacity"), NULL);
            layer.opacity = 255 * (int)opacity;
        }
        else
        {
            layer.opacity = 255;
        }

        TiXmlElement *layerDataElement;
        layerDataElement = layerElement->FirstChildElement("data");

        if (layerDataElement == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Bad map. No layer information found." << endl;
        }

        TiXmlElement *tileElement;
        tileElement = layerDataElement->FirstChildElement("tile");

        if (tileElement == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Bad map. No tile information found." << endl;
            return false;
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        while (tileElement)
        {
            int tileGID = atoi(tileElement->Attribute("gid"));
            int subRectToUse = tileGID - firstTileID;

            if (subRectToUse >= 0)
            {
                Sprite sprite;
                sprite.setTexture(tilesetImage);
                sprite.setTextureRect(subRects[subRectToUse]);
                sprite.setPosition(x * (float)tileWidth, y * (float)tileHeight);
                sprite.setColor(Color(255, 255, 255, layer.opacity));

                layer.tiles.push_back(sprite);
            }

            tileElement = tileElement->NextSiblingElement("tile");

            x++;
            if (x >= width)
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
                if (y >= height)
                    y = 0;
            }
        }

        layers.push_back(layer);

        layerElement = layerElement->NextSiblingElement("layer");
    }

    TiXmlElement *objectGroupElement;

    if (map->FirstChildElement("objectgroup") != NULL)
    {
        objectGroupElement = map->FirstChildElement("objectgroup");
        while (objectGroupElement)
        {
            TiXmlElement *objectElement;
            objectElement = objectGroupElement->FirstChildElement("object");

            while (objectElement)
            {
                string objectType;
                if (objectElement->Attribute("type") != NULL)
                {
                    objectType = objectElement->Attribute("type");
                }
                string objectName;
                if (objectElement->Attribute("name") != NULL)
                {
                    objectName = objectElement->Attribute("name");
                }
                int x = atoi(objectElement->Attribute("x"));
                int y = atoi(objectElement->Attribute("y"));

                int width, height;

                Sprite sprite;
                sprite.setTexture(tilesetImage);
                sprite.setTextureRect(Rect<int>(0, 0, 0, 0));
                sprite.setPosition((float)x, (float)y);

                if (objectElement->Attribute("width") != NULL)
                {
                    width = atoi(objectElement->Attribute("width"));
                    height = atoi(objectElement->Attribute("height"));
                }
                else
                {
                    width = subRects[atoi(objectElement->Attribute("gid")) - firstTileID].width;
                    height = subRects[atoi(objectElement->Attribute("gid")) - firstTileID].height;
                    sprite.setTextureRect(subRects[atoi(objectElement->Attribute("gid")) - firstTileID]);
                }

                Object object;
                object.name = objectName;
                object.type = objectType;
                object.sprite = sprite;

                Rect <int> objectRect;
                objectRect.top = y;
                objectRect.left = x;
                objectRect.height = height;
                objectRect.width = width;
                object.rect = objectRect;

                TiXmlElement *properties;
                properties = objectElement->FirstChildElement("properties");
                if (properties != NULL)
                {
                    TiXmlElement *prop;
                    prop = properties->FirstChildElement("property");
                    if (prop != NULL)
                    {
                        while (prop)
                        {
                            string propertyName = prop->Attribute("name");
                            string propertyValue = prop->Attribute("value");

                            object.properties[propertyName] = propertyValue;

                            prop = prop->NextSiblingElement("property");
                        }
                    }
                }

                objects.push_back(object);

                objectElement = objectElement->NextSiblingElement("object");
            }
            objectGroupElement = objectGroupElement->NextSiblingElement("objectgroup");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No object layers found..." << endl;
    }

    return true;
}

Object Level::GetObject(string name)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        if (objects[i].name == name)
            return objects[i];
}

vector<Object> Level::GetObjects(string name)
{
    vector<Object> vec;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        if (objects[i].name == name)
            vec.push_back(objects[i]);

    return vec;
}

Vector2i Level::GetTileSize()
{
    return Vector2i(tileWidth, tileHeight);
}

void Level::Draw(RenderWindow &window)
{
    for (unsigned int layer = 0; layer < layers.size(); layer++)
        for (unsigned int tile = 0; tile < layers[layer].tiles.size(); tile++)
            window.draw(layers[layer].tiles[tile]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено:

```
TiXmlElement *image;
image = tilesetElement->FirstChildElement("image");
string imagepath = image->Attribute("source");
```